# White answer area

Tags: discussion

May I seek your help to understand the white area of my response area [here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912998/computing-geodesics-or-shortest-paths). May be was some error made unknowingly? Am in dark,...if on my side ready to apologize after explanation. Please enlighten/guide in the matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to ask why there is a light-gray shading over your answer? This is a consequence of it being at score -3, answers with low scores are optically de-emphasized in this way.

Comment: Thanks for information.